# Convert infinite series with infinity limit to integral

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove this equality :

$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{16^k(p+8k+1)} = \int_0^1 \frac{16x^p}{16-x^8}dx$

I tried to use Riemann sums but I don't really know how to convert a sum without any "$n$" inside, I also tried to convert the integral into a Riemann sum without any success either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{16^{-k}}{8k+p+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 16^{-k}\int_{0}^{1} x^{p+8k} dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^p(x^8/16)^k dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^p}{1-(x^8/16)} dx, ~if~ x^8<16 \implies x <\sqrt{2}.$$
Here we have used sum of an infinite GP.

Comment: Is there any criteria to exchange infinite sum and integral ?